# Cannot resolve method 'makeText(anonymous android.view.View.OnclickListener, java.lang.String, int)'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toast

**I am getting error while creating a Toast inside ImageButton**

> Cannot resolve method 'makeText(anonymous
>   android.view.View.OnclickListener, java.lang.String, int)'

[image]

Comment: change `this` to your `ActivityName.this`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just change

```
Toast.makeText(this, "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

To

```
Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```